# Email only new rows in Google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I'm editing the [[Send single email with values from all new rows in a spreadsheet (Google Script / GAS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415273/send-single-email-with-values-from-all-new-rows-in-a-spreadsheet-google-script][1]). The function works as far as updating the Sheet, but the e-mail that is sent sends the info for all rows. I'd like it to only send e-mails from rows that have not yet been labeled 'email_fwd'.

```
function sendEmail() {

 //setup function
 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var StartRow = 1;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,17);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

 var message = "";
 //iterate loop
 for (i in AllValues) {

 //set current row
 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

 //define column to check if sent
 var EmailSent = CurrentRow[17];

 //if row has been sent, then continue to next iteration
 if (EmailSent == "email_fwd") 
     continue;

 //set HTML template for information
  message +=
      "<p><b>E-mail: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Days: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>First Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Last Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Address: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>City: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>State: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Phone: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Country: </b>" + CurrentRow[9] + "</p>" + 
      "<p><b>Phone: </b>" + CurrentRow[10] + "</p>" + 
      "<p><b>Place: </b>" + CurrentRow[11] + "</p>" + 
      "<p><b>Rank: </b>" + CurrentRow[12] + "</p>" + 
      "<p><b>Emergency Contact: </b>" + CurrentRow[13] + "</p>" + 
      "<p><b>Emergency Contact Phone: </b>" + CurrentRow[14] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Questions & Comments: </b>" + CurrentRow[15] + "</p><br><br>";

  //set the row to look at
  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

  //mark row as "sent"
  ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 17).setValue("email_fwd");
}

 //define who to send grants to 
 var SendTo = "someaddress@yahoo.com"; // + "," + "emailaddress2@gmail.com";

 //set subject line
  var Subject = "RE: Registrations";


  //send the actual email  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});
}
```

I think I just need to reset the `StartRow = FIRST ROW THAT IS NOT FOUND WITH email_fwd` but I'm not sure how to do that. Little help.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails with the typo fix **ActiveSheet** for third text line from the bottom.

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";

      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      **ActiveSheet**.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it unless there were other problems.

```
function sendEmail() 
{
   var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
   var StartRow = 2;
   var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
   var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,17);//17 is length of WholeRange so max index is 16
   var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
   var message = "";
   for (var i=0;i<AllValues.length;i++) 
   {
     var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
     var EmailSent = CurrentRow[16];
     if (EmailSent!="email_fwd")
     {
        message +=
            "<p><b>E-mail: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Days: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>First Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Last Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Address: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>City: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>State: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Phone: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Country: </b>" + CurrentRow[9] + "</p>" + 
            "<p><b>Phone: </b>" + CurrentRow[10] + "</p>" + 
            "<p><b>Place: </b>" + CurrentRow[11] + "</p>" + 
            "<p><b>Rank: </b>" + CurrentRow[12] + "</p>" + 
            "<p><b>Emergency Contact: </b>" + CurrentRow[13] + "</p>" + 
            "<p><b>Emergency Contact Phone: </b>" + CurrentRow[14] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Questions & Comments: </b>" + CurrentRow[15] + "</p><br><br>";
        var setRow = i + StartRow;
        ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 17).setValue("email_fwd");
        var SendTo = "someaddress@yahoo.com";
        var Subject = "RE: Registrations";
        MailApp.sendEmail({to: SendTo,cc: "",subject: Subject,htmlBody: message,});

    }
  }
}
```

My guess is that your headers look like this:

[image]

The numbers on the second row should be your indexes so it's possible that they should all be reduced by one.  Perhaps you can share your spreadsheet with us.

Comment: This makes it far worse ... instead of just sending one email it sends multiple emails. If I have 3 rows, it sends an email with data from all 3 rows, then another email from first 2 rows, etc. Don't know why I can't comment the answer below.

Comment: Oops! Had a bracket in the wrong place.  It should be ok now.

Comment: @Wonil is correct.  I checked this with numbers in the data and `CurrentRow[17]` does not exist in your data set.

Comment: Again I'm leaving it at `CurrentRow[17]`. Yes that creates an empty column which is what I want for ease of reading the sheet.

Comment: But CurrentRow[17] does not exist in your data set.  There are only 17 values 0 through 16.  So where is EmailSent located. We need to see your data set or we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
var EmailSent = CurrentRow[17];
```

to

```
var EmailSent = CurrentRow[16];
```

getRange's index start from 1. When you access JavaScript array for row, index start from 0.

Hint. You can use `Logger.log(CurrentRow[17]);` for debugging.

Comment: No thanks. That portion of the code is working fine.

Comment: @testing123 My fixed version working well if I don't miss understood your intention. Please check my test version document - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-kKHmz-nx1WOZni2IkYUS-GOZvo6SriU4k9_-1CAIgQ/edit#gid=0