# Google Script email send ignoring #N/A values in row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Essentially i'm also pulling email addresses from a separate sheet via a formula so that when new form entry is made, column B populates the proper email (name is included in the form). The problem I'm facing is that for the tool to be efficient I need to run the formula all the way down indefinitely so that when new entry comes it simply looks up the name and column B pulls the correct email address. However, the below code returns an error because it cannot handle #N/A where no email exists yet or even "" with IFERROR in the formula.

Ideally the code will stop if #N/A is encountered and only continues when there is an email in CurrentRow[1] has an email. The code works perfectly fine if empty rows are totally blank.

The current version here comes from what I've read and researched, including the post: [Email only new rows in Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645662/email-only-new-rows-in-google-sheets). I've researched and lots of similar examples exist but having tried 40 or so variations i could not get mine to work.

```js
function sendEmail() {

 //setup function
 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var StartRow = 2;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,11);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

 var message = "";
 
  //iterate loop
 for (i in AllValues) {

 //set current row
 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

 //define column to check if sent
 var KamEmail = CurrentRow[1];

 //if row has been sent, then continue to next iteration
   if (CurrentRow[1] == "#N/A") {break;}
     
  else;
    
     
 //set HTML template for information
  message +=
      "<p>Hi " + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p>Your constituent has submitted an Agenda blog pitch" + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Name of constituent: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +  
      "<p><b>Submission Snapshot: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Link to Submission: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Date of Submission: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p><br><br>";
  
  //set the row to look at
  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

  //mark row as "sent"
  ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 9).setValue("Sent to KAM");
}

 //define who to send grants to 
 var SendTo = CurrentRow[1];

 //set subject line
  var Subject = "RE: Registrations";


  //send the actual email  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});
}
```

Comment: Remove the semi colon after else; and I would suggest you wrap what you want as the else block in curly braces else {  whateveryouwant }.  I'm not sure how much you want in it. And it looks like the curly braces for your for loop are missplaced after "Sent do KAM".  Maybe not, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried that but I still have the same issue. Hopefully others can help!