# Send email with values for only new rows in a spreadsheet via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use a script to send an email when new rows are added to a review spreadsheet. There's a great thread on "[Send single email with values from all new rows in a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415273/send-single-email-with-values-from-all-new-rows-in-a-spreadsheet-google-script)" but I've found that when using the trigger `onEdit` for the following script I'll still receive a blank email when any edit is made, even when all rows in column 9 (the notification sent column) are marked "sent".

Is there a way to add an `if` statement to only send an email if there is a new row with a blank column 9 (so I'm not receiving blank emails with the `onEdit` trigger)?

```
function sendEmail() {

//setup function
var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
if (ActiveSheet.getName() == 'Review Tracker') {
var StartRow = 6;
var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,11);
var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
for (i in AllValues) {
  var row = AllValues[i];
  if (row[7] === "Ready for Review") {  

  var message = "";
  //iterate loop
  for (i in AllValues) {

  //set current row
  var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

  //define column to check if sent
  var EmailSent = CurrentRow[10];

  //if row has been sent, then continue to next iteration
  if (EmailSent == "sent") 
  continue;

  //set HTML template for information
  message +=
      "<p><b>Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Client: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Deliverable Title: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Link to Review Thread: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Deadline for Review: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Delivery to Client: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Notes: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Status: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" + "</p><br><br>";

  //set the row to look at
  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

  //mark row as "sent"
  ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 10).setValue("sent");
  }

  //define who to send emails to 
  var SendTo = "email@address.com";

  //set subject line
  var Subject = "New Deliverable to Review for " + CurrentRow[1];

  //send the actual email  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: SendTo,
    subject: Subject,
    htmlBody: message,
    });
  }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't end up working - still receiving emails for any edit. Wondering if setting the trigger to requiring certain value in cell "X" like "ready to review" might work better - thanks!

Comment: Updated - essentially I have the message working but cannot figure out how to specify to only send the row that is being marked as "Ready to Review". Trying to use the define column to check as "sent" as a way to prevent emails from being resent from rows that were already emailed.

Answer (score 0):

Change From

```
var Subject = "New Deliverable to Review for " + CurrentRow[1];

  //send the actual email  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: SendTo,
    subject: Subject,
    htmlBody: message,
    });
```

To

```
var Subject = "New Deliverable to Review for " + CurrentRow[1];

  //send the actual email If message is not empty
  if (message) {// Added
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: SendTo,
    subject: Subject,
    htmlBody: message,
    });
   }//Added
```

Modified Script:

```
function sendEmail() {

  //setup function
  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  if (ActiveSheet.getName() == 'Review Tracker') {
    var StartRow = 6;
    var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
    var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,11);
    var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

    var message = "";
    //iterate loop
    for (i in AllValues) {

      //set current row
      var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

      if (CurrentRow[7] == "Ready for Review" && CurrentRow[9] != "sent") {


        //define column to check if sent
        //var EmailSent = CurrentRow[10];

        //if row has been sent, then continue to next iteration
        //if (EmailSent == "sent") {
          //continue;}

        //set HTML template for information
        message +=
          "<p><b>Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Client: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Deliverable Title: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
                "<p><b>Link to Review Thread: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
                  "<p><b>Deadline for Review: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
                    "<p><b>Delivery to Client: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
                      "<p><b>Notes: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
                        "<p><b>Status: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" + "</p><br><br>";

        //set the row to look at
        var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

        //mark row as "sent"
        ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 10).setValue("sent");
      }//if review ready
    }//For loop close

    //define who to send emails to 
    var SendTo = "email@address.com";

    //set subject line
    var Subject = "New Deliverable to Review for " + CurrentRow[1];

    //send the actual email   if message is not empty
    if (message) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: SendTo,
        subject: Subject,
        htmlBody: message,
      });
    }//if message
  }//if sheetName Review
}//End Func
```

Comment: Still receiving multiple emails (1 for each row, regardless of "sent"), and all rows grouped into each email.

So for example, I have 3 total rows with "Ready to Review", even if they are marked "sent", if I add a new row and mark it as "Ready to Review", I'll receive 4 total emails (1 for each row) and within each email is 4 total messages (1 for each row).

Comment: yes - this wasn't an issue with my updated code as well after adding the if statement for "Ready to Review". Should I start a separate thread regarding my more recent question/problem?

Comment: added here - was not working - was this correct? https://www.screencast.com/t/sWbzWhy5s

Comment: It is only sending one email per row edit (as opposed to all rows as before) but still appears to be disregarding the if Email == "sent" and resending "sent" rows if there is an edit and "Ready to Review" is in CurrentRow[7].

Comment: That was totally it! I had swapped the CurrentRow[10] to 9 previously and it hadn't been working so I swapped it back - thank you thank you!