# How can I use Mails from the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using [Send single email with values from all new rows in a spreadsheet (Google Script / GAS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415273/send-single-email-with-values-from-all-new-rows-in-a-spreadsheet-google-script][1]) to send mails from a sheet on a new row to a given address. Now I Like to use a mail address from the current row. Also I like to include a link to the document in the mail message ...

This is the script I'm using:

```
function sendEmail() {

 //setup function
 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var StartRow = 3;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,22);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

 //iterate loop
 for (i in AllValues) {

 //set current row
 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

 //set subject line
   var Subject = "Neu für " + CurrentRow[1]  + ": "+ CurrentRow[2] + " für " + CurrentRow[3];

 //set HTML template for information
 var message = 
      "<p><b>Ressort: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Textart: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Domain: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Thema: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>fertig bis: </b>" + CurrentRow[15] + "</p>";

 //define column to check if sent
 var EmailSent = CurrentRow[0];

 //define who to send grants to 
 var SendTo = "xxx@yyy.com" + "," + "xxx@zzz.yyy.com";

 //if row has not been sent, then...  
 if (EmailSent != "gesendet") {

  //set the row to look at
  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

  //mark row as "sent"
  ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 1).setValue("gesendet");

  //send the actual email  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});
}
}
}
```

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Now I Like to use a mail address from the current row". To get the link to the sheet, however, you would use `var url = ActiveSheet.getUrl()` and you would have it as a string you can simply include into the email's body

Comment: thx so far ...
The script sends the new row to a mail adress which is hardcoded in the script. I like to use a mail adress instead from the new row ("CurrentRow") which is send. Do you understand me?

Comment: I think I get it; you want to get the actual "to" address from a cell in the sheet. I don't know what cell you have the information in, but you can retrieve it with `var address = ActiveSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();` (assuming the email is in cell A1) and then in your email creator you'd put `MailApp.sendEmail({ to: address,...`

Comment: And ... just in this moment I see that I need to run the script only on a specific sheet ... and another problem is: I like to run it by a time trigger which I guess is not possible with ActiveSheet ...

Comment: it is possible!, you just need to have the script bounded to the sheet, which you would do by opening the sheet, going to tools->script editor, then writing your code there, clicking the clock button next to the "run" one and that will take you to the trigger page, you can set the timer-based one in there. and this will work with activeSheet

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Personally, I would not use the active sheet. I would prefer to use getSheetByName() but I assume all this is working for you so I didn't change it. I've commented the items that I changed or added.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var StartRow = 3;
  var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
  var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,23);//Added a new column for recipient email address
  var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<AllValues.length;i++) {
    var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
    var Subject = "Neu für " + CurrentRow[1]  + ": "+ CurrentRow[2] + " für " + CurrentRow[3];
    var message = "<p><b>Ressort: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Textart: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Domain: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Thema: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" + "<p><b>fertig bis: </b>" + CurrentRow[15] + "</p>";
    var EmailSent = CurrentRow[0];
    var SendTo = (CurrentRow[22])?CurrentRow[22]:"xxx@yyy.com" + "," + "xxx@zzz.yyy.com";//conditional (ternary) operator.  If CurrentRow[22] is there then use it otherwise use your default.
    if (EmailSent != "gesendet") {
      var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;
      ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 1).setValue("gesendet");
      MailApp.sendEmail({to: SendTo,cc: "",subject: Subject,htmlBody: message});
    }
  }
}
```

[conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Thx Cooper and sorry, for not responding earlier ... I was for holidays in Sweden. I tried your version and it works well even with getSheetByName() ... But I've another problem: I like to have a formula to fetch a mailadress automatically if another cell has a specific Keyword. Because our users like this function I pre-filled the cells with the formula and without the keyword the mail-cell is empty ... But not for the script which regard the cell and the row as new an try to send a mail ... any ideas?

Comment: To make it easier for others to find the answers to specific questions we have to limit our answers to specific questions.  So I can't concatenate additional answers.  So if you have additional questions please ask them in another question.